# Laravel - Filtering previously returned results

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a page with a form, that lets you select an exercise that I have logged data for. When you submit the form, it uses a getExerciseLog method in my LogController which takes the input name, and gets all instances of that exercise from the database and shows it in a table. The table displays fine, but now I need to filter these by newest and oldest etc, using a select field.

I have created the form for this, which posts to a "filter" method in LogController. So far I have this code:

```
public function getExerciseLog()
{

    $exercises = Exercise::lists('exercise_name', 'exercise_name');

    $exercise = Input::get('exercise');

    $exercise_logs = Workout::where('exercise_name', '=', $exercise)->orderBy('created_at','desc')->get();

    return view('log')->with(array(
        'exercise'=>$exercise,
        'exercises'=>$exercises,
        'exercise_logs'=>$exercise_logs,
    ));
}

public function filter()
{

    $filter = Input::get('filter');

    if($filter == "oldest") {
        $exercise_logs = Workout::where('exercise_name', '=', $exercise)->orderBy('created_at','asc')->get();
    }elseif($filter == "newest") {
        $exercise_logs = Workout::where('exercise_name', '=', $exercise)->orderBy('created_at','desc')->get();
    }

}
```

Obviously this is not finished, as I'm stuck on how to return back to the 'log' view with the results filtered. At the moment, in the filter method, the $exercise_log won't return anything as $exercise is not being set, as the exercise input is not being submitted (that is the original select field for choosing the exercise you want to see data for).

Any ideas how I can get this working? Is it possible to pass the $exercise data from the getExerciseLog into the filter log, so I can use it within that method?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recommended way would be to sort the table using Javascript, it avoids the need of another request and full page refresh so it is much faster.

However in your case you can save the $excercise in the session like this

```
$request->session()->put('excercise', $excercise);
```

and

```
$exercise=session('excercise');
```

More info in here https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/session#basic-usage